# Redirecting a file within the same domain with an htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I moved some files around on a site recently to a different file path and I wanted to redirect the old path to the new file location using an htaccess file. I can not seem to get them to redirect properly as it just return "File not found." The site is running on an Apache server and PHP7.

```
Redirect 301 /old-path/mypage.php http://www.example.com/new-path/mypage.php
```

I have also found that the following seems to work, but I need `.PHP` on the end as this is the way it is registered on search engines.

```
Redirect 301 /old-path/mypage http://www.example.com/new-path/mypage.php
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You want to redirect users from old urls that's being indexed by search engines to new url.

So try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^old-path/(.*)$ new-path/$1 [R=301,L]
```